# How is 'suggested edit' review queue sorted?

Tags: support, review-queues

We know that maximum the size of the 'suggested edit' review queue is 500. For a research purpose, I need to know how reviews are sorted in the queue? Is it a LIFO/FIFO? Is there any way to get all the past data of this review queue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/history ?

Comment: the queues are sorted in most recent reviewed item first, kind-of. But there is a lot of complexity for each user due to things like skipped items and already reviewed etc.

Comment: Just a side note, there's no such thing as a LIFO queue, that's called a stack

Comment: History of all suggested-edit reviews till last sunday: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1381199

Comment: I'm surprised anyone is reviewing that queue given that the new UI leaves about 4 words per line now.

Comment: @Scratte - dunno, I like this review queue regardless of the UI :) What annoys me in the new one, though, is that editor reputation is hidden away (presumably intentionally) now - as previously it could be used to determine how on guard should one be when reviewing an item (not for audits, but for bad suggestions)

Comment: @OlegValter I think the new UI is just horrible. The real estate is going to things unrelated to the actual review more now than before. The view of the post as if it's on the front page seems cheap and the radiobutton box is taking way too much space. The editor now has the place of the author of the post, and the author of the post is nowhere to be seen on Answers. The idea of having tabs to switch between reviewed one and the other Answers is forcing never ending scrolling and the link to the Answer has gone missing. Which is the one to use when trying to check for plagiarism or audits..

Comment: @Scratte - valid points (would've upvoted in agreement, but I bump into voting limits the 5th day in a row with all that fuss :)). I can't say it is *horrible*, I've been able to work with it without too many issues, but it certainly would benefit from some improvements. I don't really get what business other posts have in this review queue, frankly

Comment: I don't like the new UI. I wish I could revert to the old one honestly. I wouldn't say it _sucks_ though.

Comment: @Scratte - btw, on the point of your frustration about screen real estate usage: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361376/786798

Answer (score 7):

I don't have insight on how the suggested edit queue is sorted but I have no reason to believe it is much different of what [Shog9](https://stackoverflow.com/users/811) laid out [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199912/158100) for the Close Vote queue.

> [T]he more previous reviews a given task has had, the closer to the top of the queue it'll be. [...]
> However, preference is also given to the most recently queued items

The Stack Exchange Data Explorer has the ReviewTasks and ReviewTaskResults tables with rows for each review queue. The only information missing is the user that did the review. For that you have to visit each review individually.

Here is a [rough query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1381199) to get you started:

```sql
;with taskresults as (
  select reviewtaskid
       , count(*) [all]
       , sum(case when ReviewTaskResultTypeId = 2 then 1 else 0 end) [Approve]
       , sum(case when ReviewTaskResultTypeId = 3 then 1 else 0 end) [Reject]
       , sum(case when ReviewTaskResultTypeId = 5 then 1 else 0 end) [Edit]
       , sum(case when ReviewTaskResultTypeId = 19 then 1 else 0 end) [Rej.Edt]
       , sum(case when ReviewTaskResultTypeId = 1 then 1 else 0 end) [Skip]
   from reviewtaskresults
   group by reviewtaskid
)

select concat(
         'site://review/suggested-edits/'
       , reviewtasks.id
       , '| review for '
       , case p.posttypeid 
         when 1 then 'Q: '
         when 2 then 'A: '
         when 4 then 'Excerpt: '
         when 5 then 'wiki: '
         else '? '
         end
         , coalesce(q.title, tw.tagname, te.tagname) ) [Review Link]
     , reviewtasks.creationdate
     , reviewtasks.deletiondate
     ,  [all] [# reviews]
     ,  [Approve]
     ,  [Reject]
     ,  [Edit]   
     ,  [Rej.Edt]     
     ,  [Skip]   
from reviewtasks
inner join taskresults rtr on rtr.reviewtaskid = reviewtasks.id
inner join posts p on p.id = postid
inner join posts q on q.id = coalesce(p.parentid, p.id)
left outer join tags tw on tw.wikipostid = postid 
left outer join tags te on te.excerptpostid = postid
where reviewtasktypeid = 1 -- suggested edit
order by creationdate desc
       , deletiondate asc
```

Keep in mind this data is refreshed once a week, on Sunday. It only returns 50,000 rows at once [if you don't use trickery](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234774/158100).

Additional background info on how the review system works: [Review queues architecture wrap up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360722/review-queues-architecture-wrap-up)

Comment: "[T]he more previous reviews a given task has had, the closer to the top of the queue it'll be.".. that explains how a suggested edit can sit in the queue for 5 days.

Comment: "give preference to posts that match the preferred tags" is an important bit from that architecture page.